# How to get all links containing a phrase from a changing website

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to retrieve all links from a website that contain a specific phrase.

An example on a public website would be to retrieve all videos from a large youtube channel (for example Linus Tech Tips):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/user/LinusTechTips/videos'
html = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(html.content, "html.parser")
current_link = ''
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    current_link = link.get('href')
    print(current_link)
```

Now I have 3 problems here:

- How do I get only hyperlinks containing a phrase like "watch?v="
- Most hyperlinks aren't shown. In the browser: They appear when you scroll down. BeautifulSoup does only find the links which can be found without scrolling. How can I retrieve all hyperlinks?
- All hyperlinks appear two times. How can I only choose each hyperlink once?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get only hyperlinks containing a phrase like "watch?v="

Add a single if statement above your print statement

```
if 'watch?v=' in current_link:
     print(current_link)
```

> All hyperlinks appear two times. How can I only choose each hyperlink once?

Store all hyperlinks in a dictionary as the key and set the value to any arbitrary number (dictionaries only allow a single key entry so you wont be able to add duplicates)

Something like this:

```
myLinks = {}    //declare a dictionary variable to hold your data 



if 'watch?v=' in current_link:
     print(current_link)
     myLinks[currentLink] = 1
```

You can iterate over the keys (links) in the dictionary like this:

```
for link,val in myLinks:
    print(link)
```

This will print all the links in your dictionary

> Most hyperlinks aren't shown. In the browser: They appear when you scroll down. BeautifulSoup does only find the links which can be found without scrolling. How can I retrieve all hyperlinks?

I'm unsure as to how you directly get around the scripting on the page you have directed us to but you could always crawl the links you get from the initial scrape and rip new links off the side panels/traverse them, this should give you most, if not all, of the links you want.

To do so you would want another dictionary to store the already traversed links/check if you already traversed them. You can check for a key in a dictionary like so:

```
if key in myDict:
    print('myDict has this key already!')
```

Comment: This works so far. Still having the issue with only retrieving a small amount of Urls..

Comment: Yeah, the problem with what you want to do on the last point I never went over is that the youtube page uses some form of scripting and I do not know exactly how to directly help you there, you could however visit the links inside of the new links you got and rip links to new videos from 'x' youtube page until you run out of new links. I'm not certain but I believe you should be able to acquire all of the video links from a channel in this manner.

Comment: sadly this won't help me. I didn't thought that far. I have the same issue on a non public page. YouTube was just the first page that came in my mind were I could recreate the issue.
But I could fix some of my issues. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would use the request library,

for python3

```
import urllib.request
import requests
SearchString="SampleURL.com"

response = requests.get(SearchString, stream=True)
zeta= str(response.content)
with open ("File.txt" , "w") as l:
            l.write(zeta)
            l.close()
```

`#And now open up the file with the information written to i`t

```
x = open("File.txt", "r")
    jello = []
    for line in x:

        jello.append(line)
    t = (jello[0].split(""""salePrice":""",1)[1].split(",",1)[0] )

#you'll notice above that I have the keyword "salePrice", this should be a unique identifier in the pages xpath. typically f12 in chrome and then navigating til the item is highlighted gives you the xpath if you right click and copy

#Now this will only return a single result, youll want to use a for loop to iterate over the File.txt until you find all the separate results
```

I hope this helps Ill keep an eye on this thread if you need more help.

Comment: also dont mind my variable names, I dont have a rhythm

Comment: He is using the requests library.

Comment: yeah, it looks like he updated the question as I was prepping my answer

Comment: I never edited the question. And: I honestly have no idea what I should look at in chromes f12.

Comment: Using your link in question the path you'll want to provide is //*[@id="items"]/ytd-grid-video-renderer[1]  < with the 1 incrementing for each of his videos

Answer (score 0):

### Part One and Three:

Create a list and append links to the list:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/user/LinusTechTips/videos'
html = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(html.content, "html.parser")
links = [] # see here
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href')) # and here
```

Then create a set and convert it back to list to remove duplicates:

```
links = list(set(links))
```

Now return the items of interest:

```
clean_links = [i for i in links if 'watch?v=' in i]
```

### Part Two:

In order to navigate through the site you may need more than just Beautiful Soup. `Scrapy` has a great API that allows you to pull down a page and explore how you want to parse parent and child elements with `xpath`. I highly encourage you to try Scrapy and use the interactive shell to tweak your extraction method.

[HELPFUL LINK](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)

Comment: I will have a look at Scrapy. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! And just so you know, you may want to refine your question a bit next time so you only ask one question at time. You will likely receive a more comprehensive answer if you ask a single, specific question.

Comment: I was thinking about this. But I don't wanted to spam StackOverflow with 3 questions at a time

Comment: That is understandable but the one question policy I think is paramount.

Comment: please consider marking this as the correct answer if has helped you :)